# Yaml merge in Python

Tags: python, configuration, yaml

So I'm toying around with the idea of making myself (and anyone who cares to use it of course) a little boilerplate library in Python for Pygame. I would like a system where settings for the application are provided with a yaml file.

So I was thinking it would be useful if the library provided a default yaml tree and merged it with a user supplied one. For usability sake I wonder if possible there are any out there who can divine a routine where:

In any case in the tree where the user supplied yaml overlaps the default, the user supplied branches replace the library supplied ones.

In any case where the user supplied yaml does not overlap the default tree, the default tree persists.

Any superflous branches in the tree provided by the user supplied yaml are appended.

I know this explanation was verbose as it is probably clear what I'm asking for. I wonder if it is a bit much to get for free.

Comment: How should it handle conflicting types, such as a list in the default tree, and a dictionary in the config tree? Should it merge lists, and in that case, how?

Answer (score 22):

You could use [PyYAML](http://pyyaml.org/) for parsing the files, and then the following function to merge two trees:

```
def merge(user, default):
    if isinstance(user,dict) and isinstance(default,dict):
        for k,v in default.iteritems():
            if k not in user:
                user[k] = v
            else:
                user[k] = merge(user[k],v)
    return user
```

Optionally, you could do a [deep-copy](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html) of the user-tree before calling this function.

Comment: It's default.update(user), since dict.update overwrites existing keys. To know where to recurse deeper into the tree, I would have to iterate over the joined dictionary, which is larger or equal to the largest of user and default.

Comment: very nice, thanks! Although imho it misses the merge between arrays: if a key has [1,2] and the other key has [2,3], the merged element should have [1,2,3]. am I wrong?

Comment: Then you will have to deal with repetitions and complex object equality.

Comment: This doesn't handle the case where the user file is empty. In that case `user` will be `None`.

Comment: That is only at the root-level, and should be handled before calling `merge`. It would be wrong to replace existing branches in `user` without values, with corresponding in `default`. `merge("yamlkey:", "yamlkey:3")`

Comment: @MarkusJarderot Agreed (about handling before calling merge). I was going to add that, but I see I was too slow. :-) Thanks for replying.

Comment: This took an hour for me to find, thank you.  Incidentally, for python3.6, I (only) had to change iteritems() to items()